# NSDate. Convert time and GMT to string with time and zero GMT

Tags: nsstring, timestamp, nsdate, nsdateformatter, gmt

The time is given as timestamp (in seconds). I need time only, so I take any date and add this time interval. For example:

```
NSDate *td = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
dateFormatter.locale = @"en_GB";
NSString *result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:d];
```

But it works incorrect: for 32400 it shows 12:00 (MSK) instead of 9:00.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Try last example from this demo https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html
may it help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```